# Get count from table given input from another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: `filer_info`, `filer_persent` and `persent_email`,  connected via:

```
filer_info.filer_info_id = filer_persent.filer_info_id
filer_persent.persent_info_id = persent_email.persent_info_id
```

I want to find all rows where I have multiple type PRIMARY in the `persent_email` table (ie count > 1). And the only thing I want to return in the query is `filer_info.filer_ident` and the count.

This gives me every row, but I only want the data where `filer_ident > 1` in the returned rows.

```
select * from filer_info f
inner join filer_persent fp on f.filer_info_id=fp.filer_info_id 
inner join persent_email p on fp.persent_info_id=p.persent_info_id
where fp.filer_persent_kind_cd = 'FILER' and     p.persent_email_kind_cd='PRIMARY'
order by f.filer_ident
```

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: A question like this should also provide (relevant parts of) table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  filer_ident, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  filer_info_id, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM    filer_persent fp
        JOIN    persent_email p
        USING   (persent_info_id)
        WHERE   (fp.filer_persent_kind_cd, p.persent_email_kind_cd) = ('FILER', 'PRIMARY')
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) с
JOIN    filer_info f
USING   (filer_info_id)
WHERE   filer_ident > 1
ORDER BY
        f.filer_ident
```